# style manipulation using Google Earth api

Tags: geoserver, google-earth, style, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am creating data in QGIS and then serving it using GeoServer and displaying using the Google Earth api. Is there any way to access the styles using a JavaScript api and alter the look and feel of my data, (i.e. changing colors, etc.)?

Comment: You can change the styles of features shown in Google Earth via `style` elements in the KML files. Maybe you already knew that, but you didn't use a 'kml' tag in your question.

Comment: Right I was aware of doing so by changing attributes I probably should have stated that. I was sort of hoping for a more "object-oriented" way of doing so I guess.